# How can you authenticate to using AD from an externally hosted website?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: I have a website built on a CMS that can authenticate over LDAP. I would like for users to be able to use their AD usernames and passwords to authenticate to the website.

Basically I'm trying to understand if there is a good way to make Active Directory available externally through an LDAP connection. What options are there for this sort of thing?

Researching online I've found some suggestions to set up AD LDS on our DMZ and have it replicate with our internal Domain Controller. It seems like that would work, but I don't have a very deep understanding of AD LDS, so I'm not sure.

Is there some standard way of doing this? Or is it generally considered best practice to just set up a separate user database for external use?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have all your "externally hosted website" users in your AD domain, you should be able to do LDAP authentication against any DC.

If you do not want your "externally hosted website" users in your domain, then setup a LDS instance. (But I would not put it in the DMZ. Just open a point-to-point path through the firewall to the LDS instance for port 636.)

-jim

Comment: Yes, we have all the users in our AD Domain. And we can do LDAP authentication against the DC from websites that we host here. However we're now starting to have websites hosted outside our network, so my question is what is the best way to make an LDAP connection to our domain controller from a website out on the internet?

Comment: You could do LDAPs (LDAP over SSL) to your DC form the WEB Host or use SAML which would be my preference.